# What is the correct behavior of ::before and ::after pseudo-elements on <details>?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I discovered that `<details>` is rendered differently between Chrome and Firefox. See the code example below.

According to [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#the-details-element):

> The first summary element child of the element, if any, represents the
> summary or legend of the details. If there is no child summary
> element, the user agent should provide its own legend (e.g.
> "Details").
>
> The rest of the element's contents represents the additional
> information or controls.
>
> The open content attribute is a boolean attribute. If present, it
> indicates that both the summary and the additional information is to
> be shown to the user. If the attribute is absent, only the summary is
> to be shown.

And according to [CSS Standard](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#generated-content):

> When their computed content value is not none, these pseudo-elements
> generate boxes as if they were immediate children of their originating
> element, with content as specified by content.
>
> ::before represents a styleable child pseudo-element immediately
> before the originating element’s actual content. ::after represents a
> styleable child pseudo-element immediately after the originating
> element’s actual content.

On Chrome and Chromium based browsers, `::before` and `::after` are displayed respectively before `<summary>` and after the additional information, whatever the `open` attribute is present or not. As I understand, `<summary>` is part of the details actual content, even if the tag is not defined but generated by the browser???

On Firefox, `::before` and `::after` are displayed after `<summary>` and around the additional information if the `open` attribute is present, else only the summary is shown. Based on the CSS definition, this suggests that `<summary>` is not part of details actual content. This behavior is consistent with `<fieldset>` where `::before` is also displayed after `<legend>`. However, I would expect that the two pseudo-elements remain always visible because `<details>` is still visible when closed.

So what should be the correct behavior?

```css
details::before {
  content: "before";
  color: red;
}

details::after {
  content: "after";
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Closed details</summary>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</details>
<details open>
  <summary>Open details</summary>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</details>
```

Comment: I think that your question is a little bit tricky, because you are questioning about how different Browsers decides to implement a HTML5 tag specification looking for what is the most correct or not; And since the beginning of the times -- when the world started having different browsers -- some decisions are truly arbitrary on what each browser's developer team decides. For that same reason we have different CSS render technologies, and different JS engines.

Comment: Of course you can investigate their different implementations via checking the Shadow DOM/CSS of each browser to know details about what they did on their end.

Comment: But the question looks a little bit open from my point of view. Nonetheless I can give you my personal opinion, but again how the HTML specification and the technology is applied is the decision of the browser's developers.
I think that the correct approach is what Chrome is doing, because it is more consistent about the tree representation. On the other hand it seems like Firefox reorder the elements and maybe they try to over-optimize the rendering by removing all the elements when the details tag is closed -- including pseudo elements--

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the quotes you give, it seems that Chromium is in violation of the HTML requirements (should not be shown when details is closed) and Firefox is in violation of the CSS requirements (::before should precede the summary).

However, we also have the rendering requirements from the HTML specification, which for [details/summary](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#the-details-and-summary-elements) says:

> The details element is expected to render as a block box. The element is also expected to have an internal shadow tree with two slots. The first slot is expected to take the details element's first summary element child, if any. The second slot is expected to take the details element's remaining descendants, if any.

So we only have two slots, and one slot is dedicated to the summary element. The other slot takes the remaining content, including that of the ::before and ::after pseudo elements. Such an arrangement can only be consistent with Firefox's behaviour.

---

Update: It turns out that the conclusion of the above answer is incorrect, at least according to Chrome's dev's - See the bug report.

Apparently, pseudo-elements do not ever participate in the slotting process, possibly because the process of slotting is a DOM - specifically a shadow DOM - operation. As such, at the time of slotting, pseudo elements - which are generated by the application of styling - don't exist, and therefore cannot participate in the slotting process. So they end up getting added at a later time in the rendering process around the entire already slotted arrangement, making Chromium's behaviour correct.

Comment: Interestingly, in the Firefox Inspector, `::before` does show before the summary element.

Comment: @tobiv - That makes sense. The inspector is an representation of the (augmented) DOM, not of the rendering.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I created an issue on https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1363082